# quantify a captured regex

Tags: regex, perl, quantify

I am looking for file paths within scripts. So I am going to write out a script that
cats out file and then looks for a "/".

I would rather use perl regex and would just like to grep out file paths.

```
foo@foohost:~ $ cat /sbcimp/dyn/data/FOO/GSD/scripts/FOOonoff.pl | grep "/"

#!/usr/bin/perl
my $output_file = "/sbcimp/dyn/data/stmFOO3/dailymetrics/PartRates/file6.csv";
my $input_file_name_ESTATE = "/sbcimp/dyn/sym/data/stmFOO3/part_rates/FOO_estate.$year$month1$day1.1630.csv";
my $input_file_name_ESTATE = "/sbcimp/data/stmFOO3/part_rates/FOO_estate.20140829.1630.csv";
my $input_file_name_ESTATE2 = "/sbcimp/part_rates/FOO_estate.$year$month1$day2.1630.csv";
my $input_file_name_ESTATE3 = "/sbcimp/FOO_estate.$year$month2$day3.1630.csv";
my $input_file_name_NEW = "/sbcimp/dyn/data/stmFOO3/dailymetrics/RiskTiers/new_terms.csv";
    $argVal =~ s/\s+$//;
    $argVal =~ s/^\s+//;
    $argVal =~ s/\"$//;
    $argVal =~ s/^\"//;
    $argVal =~ s/\'$//;
    $argVal =~ s/^\'//;
```

If I cat out the file and put it through a perl one liner, I get just the root directory.

```
foo@foohost:~ $ cat /sbcimp/dyn/data/FOO/GSD/scripts/FOOonoff.pl | perl -nle 'print /(\/\w+\/)/' | sort -u

/sbcimp/
```

I understand quantifiers in regex but if I use 'print /(/\w+/){1,9}/' that is not going to give me "/w+/..either 1 or 9 times. I am going to be looking for paths that are 1 or many times from the root path.
    How do I quantify the whole captured regex, not just the last character?

Comment: Should probably be `/^\/(\w+\/)+/` instead. Capturing the first for-slash, then any number of `\w+/` sequences.

Comment: The easiest way, though, would be just to remove any non-slash symbols at the end of the string (with `s~[^/]+$~~`, for example).

Comment: so this is not really quantifiable?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend not using a regular expression to parse Perl code, but instead to use [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI).

The following parses the perl lines that you provided for strings, reduces them to just their base content, and then pulls out the path information:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;
use File::Basename;

my $src = do {local $/; <DATA>};

# Load a document
my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$src );

# Find all the strings within the doc
my $strings = $doc->find( 'PPI::Token::Quote' );
for (@$strings) {
    my $str = eval 'no strict; no warnings; '. $_->content;
    next if $@ || $str !~ /\//;

    my ($name, $path) = fileparse($str);

    print "$path\n";
}

__DATA__
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $output_file = "/sbcimp/dyn/data/stmFOO3/dailymetrics/PartRates/file6.csv";
my $input_file_name_ESTATE = "/sbcimp/dyn/sym/data/stmFOO3/part_rates/FOO_estate.$year$month1$day1.1630.csv";
my $input_file_name_ESTATE = "/sbcimp/data/stmFOO3/part_rates/FOO_estate.20140829.1630.csv";
my $input_file_name_ESTATE2 = "/sbcimp/part_rates/FOO_estate.$year$month1$day2.1630.csv";
my $input_file_name_ESTATE3 = "/sbcimp/FOO_estate.$year$month2$day3.1630.csv";
my $input_file_name_NEW = "/sbcimp/dyn/data/stmFOO3/dailymetrics/RiskTiers/new_terms.csv";
    $argVal =~ s/\s+$//;
    $argVal =~ s/^\s+//;
    $argVal =~ s/\"$//;
    $argVal =~ s/^\"//;
    $argVal =~ s/\'$//;
    $argVal =~ s/^\'//;
```

Outputs:

```
/sbcimp/dyn/data/stmFOO3/dailymetrics/PartRates/
/sbcimp/dyn/sym/data/stmFOO3/part_rates/
/sbcimp/data/stmFOO3/part_rates/
/sbcimp/part_rates/
/sbcimp/
/sbcimp/dyn/data/stmFOO3/dailymetrics/RiskTiers/
```